# How to run git bash scripts on windows startup

Tags: windows, shell, sh, git-bash

I've created a shell script and for execute it I need to use **GIT BASH** with this command

```
sh scriptname.sh
```

It's possible execute this command on **GIT BASH** when windows startup automatically?

Answer (score 4):

In Windows 10:

1) Create a regular, plain text file named `myscript.txt`, for example.

2) As its contents, insert this: `sh scriptname.sh`. Save and close.

3) Rename this file to `myscript.bat` then, with your Windows Explorer, locate the file at the filesystem folder, right click on it and select "**copy**".

4) Yet on Windows Explorer, go to `<ROOT>\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp` and right click on it. Then select "**paste shortcut**" (you will need Administration rights to do it).

It's done. Every time your windows starts it runs your bash.

More info: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026268/windows-10-change-startup-apps

Comment: Make sure to add `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` in `PATH` environment variable for `sh` command to work in Command Prompt

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb no, excuse me, with my solution you don't need to change `PATH` - have you tested? Even Win11 accuse it when it's done. Please take care when dealing with someone's job and time. Thank you. Have a good year.